# Workload Identity regularly throwing "A Forbidden error was returned while attempting to retrieve an access token..." errors

Tags: node.js, google-kubernetes-engine, google-iam

We've set up our deployments to run using Workload Identity. Each deployment has its own technical identity, a GCP service account set up with the required IAM roles, and a Kubernetes service account to match (both linked as described in the Workload Identity documentation).

This all works just fine, with one small problem: *almost* **every time** a pod starts it gives this error:

```
Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information. at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/home/node/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:155:19) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) at async GoogleAuth.getClient (/home/node/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:486:17) at async GrpcClient._getCredentials (/home/node/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:88:24) at async GrpcClient.createStub (/home/node/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:213:23)
```

It then crash-loops and typically comes up later, after 2 or 3 retries. Very very odd...

To make matters worse, every now and then we get this error instead:

```
Error: 403 undefined: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Could not refresh access token: A Forbidden error was returned while attempting to retrieve an access token for the Compute Engine built-in service account. This may be because the Compute Engine instance does not have the correct permission scopes specified: Could not refresh access token: Unsuccessful response status code. Request failed with status code 403 at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/home/node/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/node/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:176:52) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/node/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:342:141) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/node/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:305:181) at /home/node/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:124:78 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

And when we see this, it's basically game over until we try all kinds of black voodoo to try and get the service back up (usually it boils down to us deleting the entire auth stuff for that service and recreating things from scratch).

Anyone has any idea what could be going on here?

Our cluster is running `1.16.13-gke.1`, and has **Istio** `1.6.7` installed (using the Istio operator).

Comment: I just wanted to add that I tried disabling the **Istio** proxy (**Envoy**) on the pods and it didn't change anything: the same error still occurred :-(

Comment: Metadata server is deploy on the node pool ?

Comment: "GKE Metadata Server" is set to "Enabled" on the node pool, yes

`gke-metadata-server-4ptlq  1/1  Running` 
`gke-metadata-server-h6rgb  1/1  Running`
`gke-metadata-server-jrbnw  1/1  Running`
etc...

Comment: I have detected an error on one of the metadata pods now:
"Handler returns surfaceable error: failure getting dirent content: surfaceable error (status 403, reason "iam_403", message "\nUnable to generate token; IAM returned 403 Forbidden: The caller does not have permission\n\nThis error could be caused by a missing IAM policy binding on the target IAM service account.\n\nYou can create the necessary policy binding with:\n\n gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \\\n --role=roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \\\n -- ..."

Comment: I'm sure that binding was there (created by an operator)... but I will try to recreate it again manually now...

Comment: Well... didn't recreate the binding, since it turns out the pods suddenly did start meantime (after 700 retries), so this "fixed itself" (which we all know never turns out to be a good thing ;-)

Comment: okay strange. If you find the real cause. Post solution here.

Comment: Did you find something new about it? If you could share how to reproduce, i can try in my lab env.

Answer (score 1):

So... the mystery has been solved.

There was an obscure but stupid but in our operator that provisions both the IAM and Kubernetes service accounts, including the necessary bindings.

There was a situation with a namespace being deleted that could end up in removing **all** the bindings to any other namespace :-(  So this explains the error above, the moment this happened we got 403 errors (obviously, looking back on it now).

Bug has been fixed today, so all should be well now.